# Xslt count number of movies

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to count the number of Students when the year is less or equal to 2005.
So far this is what I have but it returns the total number of students in the xml file and not just the one with the year less or equal to 2005.

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(students/student)"/>
```

I also tried an if statement but is not working.

```
           <xsl:if test="year &lt;=2005">
              <xsl:value-of select="count(/student[year]) &lt;=2005"/>
            </xsl:if>
```

Comment: What do you mean by not working? What results do you get?

Comment: I only get the full number of students. in total I have 15 students but only 5 of the students have year less or equal than 2005.. I only want the count of the students with &lt;=2005 which should be 5

Comment: Please create a [mcve] so that we have full context and can answer definitively.  Otherwise, all we can do is guess:  `count(students/student[year &lt; 2005])`.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to figured out by your example.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to think about what the expression

```
count(/student[year]) &lt;=2005
```

means.  It compares `count(/student[year])` to `2005` and returns true or false.  The expression

```
count(/student[year])
```

in turn counts the number of items in the value of the expression

```
/student[year]
```

which is the subset of `/student` for which the predicate `[year]` is true.

The expression `/student` matches the set of elements which are (a) children of the document node and (b) named `student` in the default namespace (in this case, I'll assume the unnamed namespace as default, so the expression matches elements whose expanded name is `{}student`).

Since in any well-formed XML document there can only be one element which is a child of the document node (one outermost element), there are several possible cases here:

- There are several outermost elements; the input is not XML and the transform errors out.
- There is one outermost element, named something other than student.  The value of `\student` is the empty set, and filtering it by `[year]` cannot make it any smaller, so your `count(...)` expression has the value 0, and the XPath expression which we started with has the value `true`.
- There is one outermost element, named student.  The value of `\student` is that one element set, and filtering it by `[year]` will either succeed (the element has a child named `year`) or fail (it has no such child).  If the filter succeeds, the `count(...)` expression has the value 1, and the XPath expression which we started with has the value `true` because 1 is less than or equal to 2005.  If the filter fails, the `count(...)` expression has the value 0, and the XPath expression which we started with has the value `true` because 0 is less than or equal to 2005

I think reading and reflecting on a basic tutorial on XPath might be helpful.